# XML searching for tags that may have data, or not

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to search for:

```
<value></value>
```

or

```
<value/>
```

I need to be able to pass if either one exists, and not fail of one type of the value is missing. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need you to provide a minimal XML sample for input, what you want to retrieve from that XML, and an example of the code you wrote to solve this problem. As is, it looks like you are only fishing for answers, not a solution to a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for how to select empty elements? This XPath should work:

```
//value[. = '']
```

This will match `<value></value>` or `<value/>` (which are equivalent), but won’t match `<value>foo</value>` or `<value> </value>` (the last one contains a space).

Comment: I am looking for values that might have data and has the full pair of tags.      If there is no data, it will have the trailing slash version, and just be one tag.

Comment: @fmorales as far as the parser is concerned, `<value></value>` is the same as `<value/>`, you can’t tell the difference between them. If you are looking for elements that _aren’t_ empty you can use `!=` instead: `//value[. != '']`.